# Where are enum for meminfo_proc_show() and variables for si_meminfo() set?

Tags: c, linux, memory, enums

I am not a developer but I understand some C concepts. However, I'm having a hard time finding where the enums (e.g `NR_LRU_LISTS`, etc) in [meminfo.c/meminfo_proc_show()](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/proc/meminfo.c#L46) and the variables (e.g. totalram_pages, etc) in [page_alloc.c/si_meminfo()](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L4673) are set.

What I meant by set is for example `NR_LRU_LISTS = 324077` for instance. What I understood there is that `LRU_ACTIVE_FILE` equals `3`, but there's no `=` operator in front of `NR_LRU_LISTS`, so it must be set somewhere else.

I've clicked on the enums/variables to see where they may be called, but there's either too much unrelevant or either non-defining references.

The last thing would be me not being aware of something, but what ?

To be honest, my goal here is to determine how /proc/meminfo 's values are calculated.

But, here my question is: Where do these enums and variables are set ?

---

**Update 1**:

The enums part is now solved, and `NR_LRU_LISTS` equals `5`.

But the `totalram_pages` part seems to be harder to find out...

Comment: If you click on `NR_LRU_LISTS` you get a page with references to all files using that. It is defined in [mmzone.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L205). And `totalram_pages` seems to be declared in [page_alloc.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L220)

Comment: Oh, sorry if I wasn't clear. By set I meant that their values are set like `NR_LRU_LISTS = 574934` for instance. What I understood there is that 'LRU_ACTIVE_FILE` equals `3`, but there's no `=` operator in front of `NR_LRU_LISTS`.

Answer (score 3):

The constants you are asking about are defined using C's "[enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum)" feature.

```
enum Foo { A = 4, B, C };
```

declares constants named `A`, `B`, and `C` with values 4, 5, 6 respectively.

Each constant with no initializer is set to one more than the previous constant.  If the first constant in an `enum` declaration has no initializer it is set to zero.

The *variables* you are asking about are defined with no initializer, at file scope (that is, outside of any function).  For instance, `totalram_pages` is defined [on line 128 of `page_alloc.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L128), with a public declaration for use throughout the kernel [on line 50 of `linux/mm.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/linux/mm.h#L50).  Because they are defined at file scope and they don't have initializers, they are initialized to zero at program start.  (This is a crucial difference from variables defined *inside* a function with no initializers.  Those start off with "indeterminate" values, reading which provokes undefined behavior.)

I do not know how `totalram_pages` receives a *meaningful* value.  This code is too complicated for me to want to track that down right now.

It sounds like you are just beginning to learn C.  Studying other people's code is a good way to learn, but you should start with *simple* programs.  The Linux kernel is not simple, and because it's an operating system kernel, it also does a lot of things that would be considered bad style or just plain wrong in any other program.  Don't start with it.

... That said, declaring a bunch of related constants using an `enum` and letting them take sequential values implicitly is totally normal and good style, and so is defining variables at file scope with no initializer and relying on them to be zero at program start.  (It is often wrong to have a global variable in the first place, but if you genuinely need one, relying on implicit initialization to zero is not wrong.)  These are things you need to understand and things you are likely to want to do yourself in due course.

Comment: My goal wasn't about learning C first, but I had no choice to learn it enough to understand how /proc/meminfo values are calculated.
So I was missing that... which means `NR_LRU_LISTS` equals `5` then.
Besides, does `totalram_pages` in `si_meminfo()` is a global variable since I couldn't find any initialization for it ? I know I'm going the -very hard- way for everyone including people who may help me (since I'm learning C), but I do really want to know how /proc/meminfo got its values.

Comment: Yes, `NR_LRU_LISTS` equals 5.   I'll add some discussion of `totalram_pages` to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and reply. Besides, I heard that some IDE could do the tracking by doing `ctrl + Mouse 1`, but the most popular one seems to be IntelliJ, which is meant for Java. Do you have any IDE that can do the same for C codes ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use any IDE myself; I've never found one that could keep up with my typing.  I investigate these things with command line tools like `find` and `grep`, and online cross-references like the one you linked to.

Comment: With [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) you can create a database file (called ctags) that has information about where functions, variables, macros are declared, etc. Programs like `vim` (and I also thing emacs) read these files so you can jump between the functions and definitions. In case of vim by putting the cursor on the function you want to inspect and pressing `ctrl+]`.